# Setting JNDI programmatically in Tomcat

Tags: spring, jndi

Wanted to ask, is there a way to add / replace JNDI resources in runtime for running Tomcat (6 or 7)?
I was looking at Spring *SimpleNamingContextBuilder*, but that is for testing purposes.
Me on the other hand, would like to have it in the "production code", and before any other comments show up, yes, I want JNDI this way (;

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I have not tested this in Tomcat.

Here is an API page.
[InitialContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html)

### A Simple technique

Replace a JNDI binding by calling unbind([the jndi name])
then bind([the jndi name], [the new value])

For example,

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
Object newDesiredValue = null; //... set this appropriately.

context.unbind("blammyJNDIName");

context.bind("blammyJNDIName", newDesiredValue);
```

This may not be enough for you though.
If you need more control, then do the following:

### Change the factory

Here is an API page.
[InitialContextFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/spi/InitialContextFactory.html)

```
System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
  YourNewContextFactory.class.getName());
```

In YourNewContextFactory class,
implement the getInitialContext methods and unbind / bind as shown above before returning the new InitialContext.